# How to implement AWS Secret Manager with Spring boot? What is the best way to do this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I have a spring boot application running in ECS container. I am storing the AWS Access key, Secret Key and Database credentials in application.properties file. I need to externalise these data. So I need to implement AWS Secret Manager to store the secrets.

https://medium.com/@husseinmoghnie/using-aws-secret-manager-to-secure-java-microservice-passwords-for-pci-dss-compliancy-9c35b6420e2b

I am following the above mentioned tutorial.  **Is it a right way to store the credentials in environment variable in production?**

I will enable secret rotation policy in AWS Secrets Manager for database secrets. How will my application can know that there is change in temporary credentials?

Can someone guide me how to implement AWS Secret Manager Efficiently with Spring Boot application? Best Industry practices.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the IAM role to access AWS Resources from ECS Task. Using the AWS Access Key, Secret Key is not a good option for Production. Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-iam-roles.html for using the IAM role in ECS Task.

For Password rotation using AWS Secret Manager refer 
https://pattern-match.com/blog/2019/06/17/springboot2-and-aws-secrets-manager/

Comment: Thank you ! I will try implementing the IAM roles for ECS tasks. Also I will check how this password rotation policy works.